# pixijs: show and hide container with all elements in it

Tags: pixi.js

I have `tab: PIXI.Container` with a bunch of sprites on it.
I believe this should be so easy, I am new to Pixi, but have knowledge in JS.

I have button. Clicking on button should show/hide given container.
However, I cannot get it work.

```
btn.on('pointerdown',(event) => this.onClick(btn, tab));
```

How should I hide container with all sprites on it?
And then how can I show back container with all sprites on it?

Comment: Try using https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html#visible - example: https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi#displaying-sprites <- here sprite is hidden using `anySprite.visible = false;` , but you can do it similarily on container too.

Comment: It works, please, add it as answer. I somehow missed visibile option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html#visible](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html#visible)

example: https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi#displaying-sprites <- here sprite is hidden using `anySprite.visible = false;` , but you can do it similarily on container too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these : 
**`anySprite.visible = false`**  
or
`anySprite.alpha = 0;`